# Includable Description on Blogger Blogspot

Tags: widget, blogger, gdata, blogspot

On the header widget, it has:

```
<b:include name='description'/>
```

And I want to reference it in the post-body (inside Blog widget), with:

```
<b:includable id='description' var='a'><data:a.description/></b:includeable>
```

But it wont print out the post description, is the code wrong? or it just cant be referenced across widgets? I've tried modify the header widget `<b:include name='description' values='description'/>` and I got blank page instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code for post description is `<data:post.snippet/>` (140 characters) or `<data:blog.metaDescription/>`.